# Adjustable voltage source 10 – 50 V and adjustable current limiter 2 – 70 mA

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-source, current-limiting, source, step-up

I would like to build a source that gives on the output an adjustable voltage from 10 V to 50 V and that current be limited from 2 mA to 70 mA
or make some circuit that let me choose 2 mA, 1 0mA, 50 mA and 70 mA for example.

Do someone know how to make a source like this one?

I was thinking to make a DC DC Step Up, and then to put an current limiter on the output of the last one. But how to make an current limiter?

Comment: current limiting is typically a feature of the IC you'd use to build a DC/DC step up converter. So, kind of built-in if you read the datasheet of a modern DC/DC converter IC.

Comment: Just curious, but what is the DC source feeding this circuit? Also, are you shooting for a power supply that supports both voltage regulation with a current limit capability like a common lab supply? Or do you actually only want those four current limits (which will have to degrade the voltage as part of the limiting process from its setpoint?) Could you write a little more about this project?

Comment: @MarcusMüller what IC DC DC step up converter do you recomend me?

Comment: Two 25V bench power supplies in series will also let you do this. Why do you want a DC-DC converter for a max dissipation of 3.5W? Just use a linear regulator. Is this for bench use or is it for production?

Comment: @Indraneel I need to make a system for production and I searching how to make it.  I need an stable voltage and limited current its for a project of R&D.

Comment: What are you using to adjust the voltage and current? Surely, potentiometer is good only for bench use. Is this *project* set once and forget, or will it need periodic human intervention?

Comment: @Indraneel Only potentiometers and the circiut of the user "analogsystesrf" Im going to make this circuit today, this circuit is for once and forget, but first I have to get the set point for our application.

Comment: It's a basic circuit and will work ok unless your current draw varies a lot. The circuit is better for constant current than constant voltage as it has current feedback, but no voltage feedback. One can try to modify it for voltage feedback if required, probably by replacing one of the zeners with a TL431.

Comment: @IndraneelIM going to try to find the tl431, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This will do that

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Kj1Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit IS casually REGULATED Voltage; you can use a 55 volt Zener to power the top of the 10Kohm potentiometer.

You can use a 1:1 transformer, if you can afford the heat dissipation in the Q1 device.
At 70mA and 100 volts across the Q1 (thus a LOW Vout), you have 7 watts to remove from Q1.

Probably use a Darlington NPN for Q1; if you do, then double the values of the two overcurrent-detect resistors.

You will have about 1 volt of ripple, at 70mA, using only 1 milliFarad of charge storage.

This circuit will have no high frequency spikes, unlike any switching regulator.

Comment: I have a doubt, Is this the correct way to put the zener diode that youve talked about (link).

And how could I control the voltage, Will the potenciometer R4 control the voltage, and will R3 control the current?

Thank you for your answer 

[link](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=x3hch4x26e37)

Comment: Why not replace a zener with a TL431 for some voltage feedback? Will make the constant voltage more stable.

Comment: @ Indraneel The OP gets to ponder that design choice. Can you discuss how much more stable the TL431 might be? Then if OP wants, I'll update the schematic to include that.

Comment: I Built the circuit, that you sent me. The results, I connect in parallel to R5 the charge (1k, 2k, 22k ohm). First I tried with low voltage (less than 20v) When I use 30V I burned all the potenciometers with a current about 100mA and 20v.

Comment: And was your Darlington in T0-220 package, with a heat sink? Where were the 1K, 2K, 22K? in parallel with R5? Power = I^2 * R; 1K at 30 volts is 0.03 amps. The power will be 0.9 watts.